# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':flutter_facebook_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_facebook_auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Multiple build operations failed.
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Share the code where the exception happens.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.